# Why doesn't the Visual Studio designer want me to change event names in code?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, windows-forms-designer

I have a question about C# Event naming conventions:

```
private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { /// CODE /// }
private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { /// CODE /// }
private void button23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { /// CODE /// }
```

The designer warned that I should leave designer code unchanged.  How then do I change the names to something more meaningful if I can't change it in the `designer.cs` file?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Increase Name" ?

Comment: Set the Name property of the control after you dropped it on the form.  Everything else is automatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try naming the buttons better. That way the event handler will read better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the names is the numbering.

the designer, by default, gives objects names like classtypeN where N is an increasing number.

Go to the designer, click on the object, go to the properties ,and rename it there.

Then you won't have your conflict with designer

Answer (score 0):

I developed a habit of renaming each control first thing after I drop them on a form. I don't like going back and renaming all event handlers from e.g. button1_Click to btnClickMe_Click. The actual convention I use depends on the project's convention but I always try not to forget about renaming controls.

Below is a link with some prefixes for common controls.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173738

You may also try the ux or _ux prefix style

www.cyberbrutus.com/naming-conventions-c/